# deep nested if statement issues

Tags: orm, php-5.3, nested-loops, forms, http-post

Ok, So I'm writing a task organizer script and I'm having some issues with marking the subtasks as complete or not complete.. my code is as follows...

```
if($_POST['finished']){ // $_POST['finished'] is an html array of check boxes
            $subtask = Subtask::find_all_by_task_id($task->id);
            foreach($subtask as $stask){
                foreach($_POST['finished'] as $fin){ 
                    if($stask->id == $fin){
                        $stask->finished_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
                        $stask->save();
                    } elseif($stask->id != $fin){
                        $stask->finished_at = "";
                        $stask->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else { // This works as expected when un-checking all checkboxes
            $subtask = Subtask::find_all_by_task_id($task->id);
            foreach($subtask as $stask){
                if($stask->finished_at != null){
                    $stask->finished_at = null;
                    $stask->save();
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem I believe is the if statement is rolling over both values(there are only two subtasks right this minute) when it gets to the last values all other $fin does not equal $stask->id anymore so those get set back to null in the DB hence making it SEEM as though they're never updated..How can I fix this whats the best route to tackle this if statement..I've tried a few variations but to no avail.

Comment: `Subtask::find_all_by_task_id` almost looks like model usage! Kewl. But what's the `$_POST['finished']` doing there unchecked? Did you turn off notices? ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using CodeIgniter and php-activerecord. It started out as a simple task organizer and now it's damn near a full blown project manager...ok not that far..but still. $_POST['finished'] is supposed to signify that a task is complete, If it's not checked it should re-enable the task..I figured it all out but I spent about a day and  a half chasing ghosts trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So a simple workaround/solution was this..

```
function completetask($tasktype, $id, $return_uri = 'edittask'){
    if($tasktype == "subtask"){
        $task = Subtask::find($id);
        if($task->finished_at == null){
            $task->finished_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
            $task->save();
            switch($return_uri){
                case 'showtask':
                    redirect('taskdisplay/showtask/' . $task->task_id);
                    break;
                case 'edittask':
                    redirect('admintask/edittask/' . $task->task_id);
                    break;
                default:
                    redirect('admintask/edittask/' . $task->task_id);
            }

        } else {
            $task->finished_at = null;
            $task->save();
            switch($return_uri){
                case 'showtask':
                    redirect('taskdisplay/showtask/' . $task->task_id);
                    break;
                case 'edittask':
                    redirect('admintask/edittask/' . $task->task_id);
                    break;
                default:
                    redirect('admintask/edittask/' . $task->task_id);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $task = Task::find($id);
        if($task->finished_date == null && $task->taskcomplete == 0){
            $task->finished_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
            $task->taskcomplete = 1;
            $task->save();
            redirect('admintask/edittask/' . $task->id);
        } else {
            $task->finished_date = null;
            $task->taskcomplete = 0;
            $task->save();      
            redirect('admintask/edittask/' . $task->id);
        }

    }


}
```